# Authentication pop-ups not working

Tags: authentication

the authentication pop ups for opening documents in sharepoint site is not functioning the way it is expected to behave, rather it opens automatically without authentication..
For security reasons i could not provide the link

Comment: how to you trigger the authentication, what mechanism is in place (Windows/NTLM) generates challenge authentication?

Comment: How are you expecting it to behave?  Are these all Office documents?  Does it behave differently for non-Office documents like PDFs?  Why are you authenticating when opening documents instead of when the user access the site?